# Attempted import error: 'animated' is not exported from 'react-spring'

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this error in React JS. I've never gotten this error ever and I literally cannot find anything on the internet. I installed react-spring. I imported it into App.js.

Attempted import error: 'animated' is not exported from 'react-spring'.

```
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
```

I already installed react-spring using: npm install react-spring

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: I just updated the question with the import code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please import 'animated' like so:

`import {animated} from 'react-spring'`

Since it's named export and not a default export. See the import statement example as guided here:
https://blog.logrocket.com/animations-with-react-spring/

Comment: It still doesn't work. I updated the question with my import code

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules and run npm install. It might take a bit since node_modules is a large file.